# IAP issue in production - iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, in-app-purchase

I published a Cordova app with iAP for iOS (using [this](https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase) plugin) but I got troubles in production. The issue is: the customer buy the product, he's correctly billed but he doesn't receive the product. For Apple he didn't bought the iAP even if I can see the payement on the Apple itunes connect platform and even if he received an OK for the purchase done. 
I tested in sandbox of course, everything was fine, but now I got an issue in production and I don't know how to debug it.
I also wrote to the Apple support but I didn't received any answer.
Do you know a way to test in production mode or to find out where is the problem?

Comment: If it's working in sandbox but not production maybe it's an issue with the product configuration in App Store Connect. Are they in the 'Approved' state? Sometimes it takes ~24hrs for products to become available for purchase after being approved.

Comment: It is approved but should I maybe update the picture because I changed the text shown in the app to buy the item? I didn't any alert from Apple about it anyway